# ¿Diferencia entre OpenCV y OpenCV-Python?

Tags: python, opencv

Mi consulta es referente a estas dos versiones, entonces, estaba preparándome a compilar OpenCV en Linux-Mint 19.3, pero encontré información relativa a OpenCV-Python en el proceso.

- ¿Poseen el mismo rendimiento?
- ¿cuál es, en estricto rigor, las diferencias entre estos dos?
- ¿me decanto por compilar?

Comment: Aquí se lo explica bien: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/de3/tutoria

Comment: ¿Desde que lenguaje vas a usar OpenCV?

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/de3/tutorial_py_intro.html Sí, de hecho, estaba leyendo en el mismo sitio.
Lo voy a usar desde python. 
Me preocupaba alguna diferencia de rendimiento, o si el hecho de compilar era mejor en el sentido de que estaría "mejor" adaptado al tarro que tengo por computadora.

Comment: 1) python-opencv necesita opencv, 2) en linux tienes dos posibilidades, o usas los paquetes binarios de los repositorios o descargas los fuentes y compilas los mismos.  ¿Compilarlo es mejor? depende, si hay optimizaciones que se puedan activar por la plataforma en que lo usas, es posible.